# (android) when i declare a fragment in xml layout, i cant get data in fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SampleData data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ShowFragment showFragment = (ShowFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.showfragment);

        data = new SampleData("ABCD", "20201031");
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable("key", data);
        showFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/showfragment"
        android:name="com.example.test2.ShowFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

***ShowFragment.java***

```
public class ShowFragment extends Fragment {
    SampleData sampleData;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        sampleData = bundle.getParcelable("key");
        Log.d("CHECK", "data : " + sampleData.title);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container2,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_show, container2, false);

        textView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        textView.setText(sampleData.title);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

***ERROR MESSAGE***

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test2/com.example.test2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15 in com.example.test2:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #15 in com.example.test2:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15 in com.example.test2:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #15 in com.example.test2:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15 in com.example.test2:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Parcelable android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

I want to pass data from activity to fragment using fragment in XML (  )
but i can't get data.

If i pass the data from activity to fragment. i just get ERROR(null object reference) at getParcelable...

i dont know what's wrong.

when pass the data using fragment in xml, why i cant get data?
tell me why please

when pass data from activity to fragment in xml, how can i get data using getArgument?

Comment: Your fragment is created before you even create the bundle for your data to pass. If you want to pass data dont set the fragment in your xml layout file and create it manually in onCreate

Comment: @tyczj thx. your mean is creating dynamically? and your answer is related to lifecycle?

when use fragment in xml , is there any way to use setArgument,getArgument?

please understand, i cant use eng very well ..TT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to pass data from activity to fragment

Why? The fragment can always access the activity by calling `requireActivity()`

What data do you actually want to pass? There is probably another and even better way to get your data to the fragment. You could have a getter in the activity, a setter in the fragment or even better work with ViewModels.

---

Update

Simple option:

in your fragment, add:

```
public void setTitle(String title) {
    Log.d("CHECK", "data : " + title);
}
```

In your Activity,

```
ShowFragment showFragment = ...;
showFragment.setTitle("Test");
```

Comment: thx, but i just know how to pass data when fragment in xml..
using setArgument.. using getArgument..

Comment: There are a few simple and some would say ugly methods to get data in. But I seriously suggest you are up to learn something new and up to date and get into ViewModels